# Interpretation of fictitious forces arising from convection in fluid flow in a curvilinear coordinate system

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, coordinate-systems, convection

the time rate of change of linear momentum of a fluid with density $\rho$ and velocity vector $\mathbf{u}$ is given by the material derivative:
$$\frac{\mathrm{D} \rho \mathbf{u}}{\mathrm{D}t} = \frac{\partial \rho \mathbf{u}}{\partial t} + \mathrm{grad}\left(\rho \mathbf{u}\right)\cdot\mathbf{u}$$
The term $\mathrm{grad}\left(\rho \mathbf{u}\right)\cdot\mathbf{u}$ (fictitious forces/change of linear momentum due to convection) can be written as:
$$\mathrm{grad}\left(\rho \mathbf{u}\right)\cdot\mathbf{u} = \left[ \frac{\partial \rho u^j \mathbf{g}_j}{\partial \Theta^i} \otimes \mathbf{g}^i \right] \cdot \left[ u^k \mathbf{g}_k \right] = \frac{\partial \rho u^j \mathbf{g}_j}{\partial \Theta^i} \left[\mathbf{g}^i \cdot u^k \mathbf{g}_k \right] = \left[ \frac{\partial \rho u^j }{\partial \Theta^i} \mathbf{g}_j + \rho u^j \frac{\partial \mathbf{g}_j }{\partial \Theta^i} \right] u^i =  u^i \frac{\partial \rho u^j }{\partial \Theta^i} \mathbf{g}_j + \rho u^i u^j \frac{\partial \mathbf{g}_j }{\partial \Theta^i}$$
(Using the notation in Itskov: Tensor Algebra and Tensor Analysis for Engineers. $u^i$ is a contravariant vector component, $\mathbf{g}_i$ is a covariant basis vector, $\mathbf{g}^i$ is a contravariant basis vector and $\Theta^i$ are the parameters (?) defining the current location in the coordinate system (for example radius, angle and axial position in a cylindrical coordinate system))

The interpretation of the term $$u^i \frac{\partial \rho u^j }{\partial \Theta^i} \mathbf{g}_j$$ is easy: It is the fictitious force/change of momentum in the $j$ direction that arises due to the fluid having a non-zero flow velocity in direction $i$ **and** having a non-zero gradient of the $j$ momentum component in that same direction (direction $i$). For example: $i$ is the radial direction and $j$ is the circumferential direction. The fluid has a positive radial velocity component ($u^r>0$) **and** the circumferential momentum $\rho u^\varphi$ is smaller at a smaller radius **and** is larger at a larger radius than the current radius, thus $$\frac{\partial \rho u^\varphi }{\partial \Theta^r} > 0.$$ Then cirumferential momentum is transported to a larger radius.

**Now my question:** How can I interpret the term $$\rho u^i u^j \frac{\partial \mathbf{g}_j }{\partial \Theta^i} ?$$ **How does a curved coordinate line lead to a momentum transport?**

Comment: Is this the correct answer? Assume a cylindrical coordinate system with unit basis vectors and i = phi and j = r. Then ρ u^i u^j [d g_j / d Theta^i] = [ρ u_phi] u_r / r. Does this mean that the linear momentum component ρ u_phi is "spread out" over a larger "area" as it is transported in centrifugal direction or "compressed" into a smaller "area" as it is transported in centripetal direction? Because the radius lines "spread out" as the radius increases?